apache camel http proxy not working or works with unavailable proxyAuthHost?
I am new to Apache Camel and learn from coding.
My simple router is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd ">

    <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="timer:timer?repeatCount=1"/>
            <to uri="https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any"/>
            <log message="${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</beans>

and the test for this router is
@CamelSpringBootTest
public class JokeIT {

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @Test
    void  test_positive() throws InterruptedException {
        NotifyBuilder notification = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
                .from("timer:timer?repeatCount=1").whenDone(1)
                .create();
        camelContext.start();
        notification.matches(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
        camelContext.stop();
    }

}

I run test as
mvn clean compile test-compile failsafe:integration-test

Test passed and prints response body as expected.
But what is strange that it passed even with
<to uri="https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any?proxyAuthHost=abcd"/>

I tried set proxyHost in query string with the same result. The test still prints response body.
How it can be? Or I missed something?
I expect the test should fail with unavailable proxy.
Minimal reproducible example can be found at https://github.com/alepekhin/camel-proxy
Thank you in advance.

I think, you also have to specify the proxyAuthPort. It will only pickup the proxy config and configure the proxy with both values present.

@Raphi1 thank you, it helps. Now it writes "abcd: Temporary failure in name resolution"  as expected
